# In pandas how to convert notation to a whole number?

Tags: python, pandas, integer, scientific-notation

In python3 and pandas I open a CSV like this:

```
import pandas as pd
kwargs = {'sep': ';', 'dtype': str, 'encoding': 'utf-8'}
df = pd.read_csv("COVID_sp_29_mai_2020.csv", **kwargs)

df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 7119 entries, 0 to 7118
Data columns (total 27 columns):
 #   Column                          Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------                          --------------  ----- 
 0   Secretaria                      7119 non-null   object
 1   Assunto                         7119 non-null   object
 2   13979                           7119 non-null   object
 3   Valor de Empenho no Processo    7119 non-null   object
 4   Órgão                           7119 non-null   object
 5   Código UG Documento             7119 non-null   object
 6   Descrição Processo              7119 non-null   object
 7   Finalidade                      7119 non-null   object
 8   R$ Empenho                      7119 non-null   object
 9   Tipo Documento                  7119 non-null   object
 10  Data Atualização                7119 non-null   object
 11  R$ Pago                         7119 non-null   object
 12  Número Empenho                  7119 non-null   object
 13  Número Documento NE Ref / Anul  335 non-null    object
 14  Número Processo                 7119 non-null   object
 15  CGC CPF                         7026 non-null   object
 16  Nome Credor                     7119 non-null   object
 17  Data Emissão                    7119 non-null   object
 18  Ação Orçamentária               7119 non-null   object
 19  Fonte                           7119 non-null   object
 20  Código Fonte                    7119 non-null   object
 21  Descrição                       7119 non-null   object
 22  Unnamed: 22                     0 non-null      object
 23  Unnamed: 23                     0 non-null      object
 24  Unnamed: 24                     0 non-null      object
 25  Unnamed: 25                     16 non-null     object
 26  Unnamed: 26                     17 non-null     object
dtypes: object(27)
memory usage: 1.5+ MB
```

The column has 'CGC CPF' has identification codes, which can sometimes only have numbers or numbers and letters

The lines that the identification code 'CGC CPF' has only numbers the file is notated. Example:

```
Educação;Merenda em Casa;regular;81.508.955,00 ;SECRETARIA DA EDUCACAO;80358;MERENDA EM CASA;MERENDA EM CASA;-40280955;NE;29/05/2020;0;2020NE00119;2020NE00120;20407/20;2,29E+13;PICPAY SERVICOS S/A;01/04/2020;FORNEC. ALIMENTACAO P/ALUNOS EDUCACAO BASICA;Federal;5003002;DISPENSA DE LICITACAO;;;;Data Atualização;Data Atualização
```

In this case, the code for this line is "2,29E+13" in the CSV. It's a company code, which I know is "22896431000110"

Please, how can I convert the column notation to an integer?

I want to convert the exponential notation value to int. And also with that I will check if the CSV value is correct

Comment: If it's like that in the CSV that you get, you cannot revert it back to the original value, and it's an error in how the CSV is exported. On the other hand, if you mean that the value is correct in the CSV and when you read it you get the exponential notation, you can read it as a string and convert it with `int` if you need it as an integer

Comment: Thank you very much @ChatterOne I want to convert the exponential notation value to int. And also with that I will check if the CSV value is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
df['CGC CPF'].fillna('UNK', inplace=True)
df.loc[:, 'CGC CPF'] = df.loc[:, 'CGC CPF'].str.replace(',','') #replacing ',' in target column with blank, for us to interpret exponential values
match = ['E+','e+'] #Since there are both e+ and E+ notation
df['CGC CPF'] = df['CGC CPF'].apply(lambda x: float(x) if any(m in x for m in match) else x)  #using float to convert exponential to a number
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Rohitupadhyay  But it remained as "2,29E+13"

Comment: Thank you again @Rohitupadhyay I had this error (TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable). The CSV link to help - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1spLwZAwEjlWgaFZ4MS652TWcw7l8fsom/view?usp=sharing

Comment: please see updated answer, Nulls in the 'CGC CPF' column was causing the error. Replaced Nulls with UNK.

Comment: Thank you, but the value remains as "2,29E+13"

Comment: updated E to e while searching for keyword. It should work now.

Comment: Unfortunately not yet. The result was "229E+13"

Comment: My bad, so there are both e+ and E+ in the dataset, please use updated answer. I checked on my end with the data you shared, and its working fine.

Comment: This cannot possibly work. The numbers `22896431000110` and `22896431000000` will both be represented as `2,29E+13`, and there is no way to get back the original number: the information is lost. This will always give you `22900000000000` (not even 2289...), which is way I said that the issue is in the input data (the CSV).

Comment: Thank you. It really is not a reliable value. I will try to get a better database, the source is a public institution